# How to display update error message using Javascript in Rails controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a partial to update a record inside my Rails app. The update process is going well and javascript is responding good when the update process is success.

But, I'm wondering, how do I `alert()` something back to user if the record that they're trying to update was not successful?

Do I need to create `update_error.js.erb` file and call it inside the `else` block of my `update` controller action?

**daily_orders_controller.rb**

```
def update
    if @daily_order.update( daily_order_params.merge({default_order:false}) )
        respond_or_redirect(@daily_order)
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

**update.js.erb**

```
$('#orderModal').modal('hide');
$("li[data-order=<%= @daily_order.id %>]").html("<%= j render partial: 'calendars/daily_order', object: @daily_order, locals: { blank: true }  %>")
```

**calendar.js.erb**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_update', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: location.pathname + '/popup',
    type: "POST",
    data: { "daily_order_id": 1 }
  });
});
```

Comment: if it failed you should have errors populated under you @daily_order variable, then you just need to render it in your view, if you wish to alert just do if @daily_order.errors.presnet? then alert('asdasd');